# How to make text vertical align center next to a checkbox?

Tags: html, css

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

span:before {
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  font-style: normal;
  content: 'O';
  margin-right: 3px;
  font-size: 30px;
 }

input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ span:before {
  content: 'Z';
}
```

```html
<label>
<input type="checkbox"/>
<span>Text</span>
</label>
```

Is any way can make text in the middle next to css content?

Comment: if you add `top: 5px;
  position: relative;` to `span:before ` it should llok well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the following into the `span:before` element:

```
span:before {
   vertical-align: middle;
   position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `display: flex` and `align-items: center` on `span` element.

```css
span {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}
span:before {
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  font-style: normal;
  content: 'O';
  margin-right: 3px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ span:before {
  content: 'Z';
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <span>Text</span>
</label>
```

Comment: Ahh I was trying to answer this but did it wrong by using `flex` on `<label>`. Nice job

Comment: Simply adding `vertical-align:middle` to `:before` does the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

Just add

```
    vertical-align:middle;
```

to

```
    span:before {
      font-family: "FontAwesome";
      font-style: normal;
      content: 'O';
      margin-right: 3px;
      font-size: 30px;
      vertical-align:middle;
     }
```

Comment: This is the simplest and most correct answer that will work in all browsers without relying on the availability of flex as too many people immediately jump to for everything nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `display` of the span to `flex` and aligning the items `center` would work.

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

label span {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

span:before {
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  font-style: normal;
  content: 'O';
  margin-right: 3px;
  font-size: 30px;
 }

input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ span:before {
  content: 'Z';
}
```

```html
<label>
<input type="checkbox"/>
<span>Text</span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add vertical-align:sub to span:before

Here is js fiddle link - 
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w0bk2usL/1/)

```
span:before {
 font-family: "FontAwesome";
 font-style: normal;
 content: 'O';
 margin-right: 3px;
font-size: 30px;
 vertical-align:sub;
}
```